# How can I pass a URL querystring variable dynamically to a composed graphql query in react?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I am attempting to build a component using date from a graphql query but cannot see how dynamically supply a variable if it is not available in props when my component is created. eg. I have:-

```
class UsageComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        const params = this.queryStringParse(window.location.href);
        const queryStringImageId = params.id;

        const imageDetailsResults = this.props.getImageDetails.imageByImageId

        (etc...)
    }
}



const GET_IMAGE_DETAILS_QUERY = gql`
    query getImageDetails($imageId: Int!){
        imageByImageId(imageId:$imageId) {
            filename
            originalFilename
            width
            height
            description
            (etc...)
        }
    }
`;


export default compose(
        graphql(GET_IMAGE_DETAILS_QUERY, {name: "getImageDetails", options: props => { return { variables: { imageId: 123456 }}; }}),
        graphql(GET_PUBLICATIONS_QUERY, {name: "getPublications"})
)(ImageBrowser);
```

Which works fine. i.e. imageDetailsResults is populated and I can use the data subsequently in the render function.

However I would like to be able to replace that hard set "imageId: 123456" in the composed graphql with the queryStringImageId value I get in the component render.

I don't think I am able to set this a props value as I'm coming to this component page from a redirected url:-

```
<Switch>
    <AuthRoute path="/image" component={ImageBrowser} token={token} />
</Switch>
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: `props` is the key - `props => { return { variables: { imageId: props.someImageId }};`

Comment: I don't have that imageId in the props for the component initially though. I don't think I can set it in the props either hence the question...

Comment: then move url param extraction into this function (props => { process url .. return variables with id })

Comment: Cheers! That did the job... Only thing is that I cut down that compose list above to keep the example simple. I've actually multiple graphql queries that would use that same imageId. Is my only option to repeatedly call that same url param extraction function?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for a method to use urls like `/image/123456`.

With react-router-dom you can define route with param:

```
    <AuthRoute path="/image/:id" component={ImageBrowser} token={token} />
```

This way component gets router's prop passed in, `match.params.id` in this case ... and we're only one step away from final param passing:

```
export default compose(
    graphql(GET_IMAGE_DETAILS_QUERY, {
      name: "getImageDetails", 
      options: props => { 
        return { variables: { imageId: props.match.params.id }};
      }}),
    graphql(GET_PUBLICATIONS_QUERY, {name: "getPublications"})
)(ImageBrowser);
```

Comment: Awesome work around here @xadm. What if in a case whereby the value is not in the URL? For instance, you need to use a value which is in state?

Comment: @CalebRotich just use `<Query/>` component? state in parent - use directly?

Comment: does that mean it is not possible to make a query which depends on variables from the state without avoiding the <Query /> component?

Comment: @CalebRotich you can use any method (you're familiar with) to pass state value into query variable - using a `<Query />` component is the easiest one - rendering HOC-ed child (state in parent passed as prop) makes the same sense